# Highchart 5: Pie Drilldown labels and back button not visible

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

I try to get a Highcharts pie drilldown chart working. Seems like in Version 5 of Highcharts, the back button is not visible as well as the data labels as soon as entering level 2:

The code is the exact code from the Highcharts demo page (version 4).

[Here is my JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14vxzeL3/)

```js
$(function () {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the slices to view versions. Source: netmarketshare.com.'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}%'
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                y: 56.33,
                drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
            }, {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 24.03,
                drilldown: 'Chrome'
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                y: 10.38,
                drilldown: 'Firefox'
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                y: 4.77,
                drilldown: 'Safari'
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                y: 0.91,
                drilldown: 'Opera'
            }, {
                name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                y: 0.2,
                drilldown: null
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                data: [
                    ['v11.0', 24.13],
                    ['v8.0', 17.2],
                    ['v9.0', 8.11],
                    ['v10.0', 5.33],
                    ['v6.0', 1.06],
                    ['v7.0', 0.5]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Chrome',
                id: 'Chrome',
                data: [
                    ['v40.0', 5],
                    ['v41.0', 4.32],
                    ['v42.0', 3.68],
                    ['v39.0', 2.96],
                    ['v36.0', 2.53],
                    ['v43.0', 1.45],
                    ['v31.0', 1.24],
                    ['v35.0', 0.85],
                    ['v38.0', 0.6],
                    ['v32.0', 0.55],
                    ['v37.0', 0.38],
                    ['v33.0', 0.19],
                    ['v34.0', 0.14],
                    ['v30.0', 0.14]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                id: 'Firefox',
                data: [
                    ['v35', 2.76],
                    ['v36', 2.32],
                    ['v37', 2.31],
                    ['v34', 1.27],
                    ['v38', 1.02],
                    ['v31', 0.33],
                    ['v33', 0.22],
                    ['v32', 0.15]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                id: 'Safari',
                data: [
                    ['v8.0', 2.56],
                    ['v7.1', 0.77],
                    ['v5.1', 0.42],
                    ['v5.0', 0.3],
                    ['v6.1', 0.29],
                    ['v7.0', 0.26],
                    ['v6.2', 0.17]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                id: 'Opera',
                data: [
                    ['v12.x', 0.34],
                    ['v28', 0.24],
                    ['v27', 0.17],
                    ['v29', 0.16]
                ]
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think Highcharts 5 is still preview version and may have bugs. As per their site: "We're showing you an early candidate for Highcharts 5, and there will be bugs. But we're eager to get feedback at this stage, before polishing the new features. Feel free to test it out to see how it works for you." Ref: http://www.highcharts.com/news/215-highcharts-5-preview...

Comment: I think that here you can find similar issue on highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5723

Comment: Thanks. I think this question is obsolete, cause it's a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Grzegorz pointed out, this is a bug in the pre-release version of Highcharts 5.